# Update List in FutureBuilder using GetX in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-getx

I'm using the FutureBuilder with GetX and I want to update(add, Edit  or remove) the below type of list.

```
  var cardListDetails = Future.value(<CardRenterModel>[]).obs;
```

Thanks in advance